# Try-Catch inside while loop exits after first Exception

Tags: c#, windows-services, try-catch

I have a Windows service that runs the following `Initialize()` method immediately after being instantiated.

```
public async virtual void Initialize()
{
    bool initSuccess = false;
    int retry = 1;
    while (!initSuccess && retry <= 10)
    {
        try
        {
            schedulerFactory = CreateSchedulerFactory();
            scheduler = GetScheduler();
            initSuccess = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.Error(string.Format("Server initialization failed, retry #{0} of 10 / Error message: {1}", retry, ex.Message));
            retry++;
        }
        Task startTimer = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(10000);
        });
        await startTimer;
    }
}
```

So if the initialization fails, I would like to give the server 10 more tries to start. The code that calls the above function is:

```
QuartzServer server = new QuartzServer();
server.Initialize();
return server;
```

For some reason, this `Initialize()` method quits after the first iteration. That means my while loop seems the be useless although I can see in my log that the `Exception` is caught. Can anyone detect anything wrong with the logic of the code?

Comment: You could provide exception so that we could have a look at at. .

Comment: _"I would like to give the server 10 more tries to start"_ - that's normally controlled by Windows Service Manager itself.  You can see it on the **Recovery** tab.  Rolling your own recovery that does not send service updates might make Windows think your service is not responding to the *Start* command.  Consider sending service notifications

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initialize is an `async void` method, which normally should be avoided and only be used for event handlers. The reason is that it's impossible to wait for completion for such a method since it doesn't return a `Task`. The first time you reach the `await startTimer` statement `Initialize` will return control to its caller so it looks like the while loop has been exited, when in fact it hasn't.

Comment: Makes sense, should I make my `Initialize() ` method to return a `Task ` instead?

Comment: @Pedram Why does it even need to be `async` at all?

Comment: @Pedram you can make it return a `Task`, but you also must be sure to wait for its completion, because `await` will return control back to the caller in any case.